# How to check for column content in Bash

Tags: bash

I am stuck with this problem.
Using Bash, we have to check if the .txt file presents data for two columns , and if not, annotations have to be emptied .
Data is a txt file as follows :

```
#pacId  locusName   Best-hit-arabi-name arabi-defline
23158591    Lus10000002.g   AT1G75330.1 ornithine carbamoyltransferase
23170978    Lus10000003.g   AT1G14540.1 Peroxidase superfamily protein
```

I have to Empty annotations with no "Best-hit" & "arabi-defline" columns

I am thinking of doing a while script reading each line , but I don't know what would be the code to check if the columns are empty.

Thanks for helping me out !

Comment: Provide example with data

Comment: Awk is your fríend

Comment: we haven't learned how to use it at all...

Comment: empty the columns or remove the columns? What is the column delimiter?

Comment: What do you mean by `empty annotations`? What are `annotations`? Is this file the one you have to modify or is this just a reference file? As @Marco asked, what is the delimiter? Could you give us data where we can actually see what data is in which column? Is the "using bash" really a necessity? I'm asking because awk is way more suited to such tasks. Please give us something tangible to work with

Answer (score 0):

> I have to Empty annotations with no "Best-hit" & "arabi-defline" columns

I'll assume that you mean:

> I have to remove the line that doesn't contain value for the `Best-hit` and `arabi-defline`

So if it's the case, here a simple solution using `awk`:

```
awk '{if ($3 && $4){print $0}}' test.txt
```

I think `awk` is a better fit than `bash` in this case but you can also do it using bash with something like:

```
while read -r pacId locusName bHAN aD; do [[ $bHAN && $aD ]] && echo "${pacId} ${locusName} ${bHAN} ${aD}"; done < test.txt
```

Of course if you want to change the default separator by something else than any blank, you can just override the `IFS` like this:

```
while IFS='\t' read -r pacId locusName bHAN aD; do [[ $bHAN && $aD ]] && echo -e "${pacId}\t${locusName}\t${bHAN}\t${aD}"; done < test.txt
```

Same thing for `awk`, you'll just have to use `-F` to change the default separator.